# Android: How do I avoid imageview to get hidden when it is dragged out of its specified layout height and width limits

Tags: android

I am developing a game where i have to drag and drop images on specified pattern.So that if the pattern matches the dragged image with the dropped specified image then it gets pasted at that pattern.I have developed the code for the drag and drop and has a a logic to achieve further but stuck up in very small logic i.e. **If i provide layout-width and height as "match-parent" of image view then i can drag it through out the screen but as i have sequence of 4 images placed horizontally then i am forced to give wrap-content but then when i drag the image outside it specified limits it gets hidden and hence only visible within its dimension  ** I know its showing the characteristics which it suppose to but i am stuck both ways.Please help me out.

When Activity is created:-[image]

When i try to move or drag the image it starts getting hidden:-[image]